# CSS list navigation doesn't obey width rules

Tags: css

i'm using an unordered list to create a 3 tiered navigation. For some reason when i set the width to my 3rd tier, it doesn't stick. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks guys. Here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/VnUMF/ and you can see this problem by going over resources > engineering library.

Comment: #1 rule of styling lists: other than position and floats, put all your styling on the A-tag and use *display:block*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width on `#subItemsR li a`. This will override the width you have set for `#navList li a`, which is what currently applies to all the menu links.

Answer (score 0):

You've overridden the width with this:

```
#navList li a
```

Comment: You may have noticed it was easy to diagnose. The best advice I have for beginners is to use Chrome or the Firebug add-on for Firefox. With Chrome, right-click the element you want to look at. Hit "inspect element." On the right, it shows you the inheritance of the CSS. You can alter/disable these on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... i'll definitely look into it for chrome!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to apply the width to `#subItemsR li a` it would work.  Optimally, however, you ought to just let them auto-width if you can.

Comment: The problem with auto-width is that each box seems to appear to be a different size. I would've like it auto-width so that the longest word leads the width and all the other links follow suit.